# Как в yii2 пользоватся INSERT используя стандартную модель ActiveRecord

Tags: php, sql, yii2, framework

Видел реализацию где `SELECT` запрос осуществляется через расширение класса модели **ActiveRecord**. Там используются стандартные методы этого класса примерно так:

```
$my = myclass::find()->limit()->all();
```

где myclass - это производный класс от ActiveRecord.

А как работать например с `INSERT` инструкцией по этой же аналогии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создание новой записи модели (`insert`) осуществляется следующим образом

```
// создаем новый экземпляр класса модели
$model = new User;
// заполняем поля данными
$model->name = 'YII';
$model->email = 'yii2@framework.com';
// выполняем сохранение
$model->insert(); // или используйте метод save
```

Comment: отлично работает, спасибо